# The keyword 'class' in Javascript doesn't appear in normal javascript code

Tags: javascript

Javascript programmer doesn't use the keyword 'class' normally.

I just want to know why.

Below code looks so easy to undetstand and easy to use 'extend' concept

```
 class Animal {
                constructor(type){
                    this.type = type;
                }
                static isAnimal(obj, type){
                    if(!Animal.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj)){
                        return false;
                    }
                    return type ? obj.type === type : true;
                }
            }

            class Dog extends Animal {
                constructor(name, breed){
                    super("dog");
                    this.name = name;
                    this.breed = breed;
                }
                bark(){
                    alert("ruff, ruff");
                }
                print(){
                    alert("The dog " + this.name + " is a " + this.breed);
                }
                static isDog(obj){
                    return Animal.isAnimal(obj, "dog");
                }
            }

            var sparkie = new Dog("Sparkie", "Border Collie");
            sparkie.bark();
```

Comment: [ecma6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) has class declaration.

Comment: So Bhojendra Ndepal, you mean that older version of javascript ( older than ecam6) doesn't support class keyword?

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: I just want to know why most of codes ( like google.com) do not use class keyword normally, jfriend00.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, Javascript is prototype-based, not class-based.  Though some of the mechanisms might appear similar to folks that come from other programming languages, internally, the mechanisms that link objects are not the same as those that link classes to create inheritance, instances, etc as in class-based languages like Python, Ruby, Java, etc.

Kyle Simpson covers this topic much more thoroughly in his online writings and in his OSS book series YDKJS (especially the one titled `this and Object Prototypes`)

- [JS Objects: Inherited a Mess](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-objects)
- [`this` & Object Prototypes (Chapter 4: Mixing (Up) "Class" Objects)](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch4.md)

The implementations that refer to JS object-oriented styles, are just several different patterns to approximate class-based mechanisms in other languages.  There are several different Javascript OO patterns that you might encounter out in the "wild".  Seven of those are outlined here:

- [Object Oriented JavaScript Pattern Comparison](https://john-dugan.com/object-oriented-javascript-pattern-comparison/)

As one of the commenters noted, ES6 does have the `class` keyword, but that is just "dressing" over the existing mechanisms in JS.  It's not going to change the fact that JS will continue to be prototype-based rather than class-based.

Comment: That's awesome Links.